# How to get invisible data from website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I need fiverr service delivery times but I could get just first package's(Basic) delivery time. How can I get second and third package's delivery time? Is there any chance I can get it without using Selenium?

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get("https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent")

# BEAUTIFULSOUP

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.find_all("b", class_ = "delivery"))
```

Comment: You can answer this question on your own by studying the page source. If the artifact you need is dependent on client-side dynamic programming then BeautifulSoup won't help you.

Answer (score 1):

The data that the url contain which is dynamic meaning data is generated by JavaScript and BeautifulSoup can't render javaSceipt.So, You need automation tool something like selenium with BeautifulSoup. Please just run the code.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url ="https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent"
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(8)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.close()


print(soup.find("b", class_ = "delivery").text)
```

Output:

```
7 Days Delivery
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) to print the text ***7 Days Delivery*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent')
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "b.delivery").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent')   
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//b[@class='delivery']").text)
  ```

---

To extract the text ***7 Days Delivery*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "b.delivery"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.fiverr.com/volkeins/provide-10x-dofollow-backlinks-from-amazon-da96-permanent')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//b[@class='delivery']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  7 Days Delivery
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

With `requests.get('https://...').text`, you will receive the html content of the page. The problem is that most modern websites use client-side-rendering to built up the content for the page, so you will need javascript to render the page as your web browser does. You can use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to achieve this.